# How to add full trust for assembly?

Tags: c#, iis, sharepoint, trust

I'm trying to set full trust for my assembly for a specific .NET trust level (this assembly will be running in some web applications in SharePoint). I know this is possible using CasPol.exe but I would like to do that using API only and not with another executable.

More details:

- Under IIS → Sites, I have "MySite".
- Under "MySite" → ASP.NET → .NET Trust Levels → the selected trust level is "WSS_Minimal" (and the path to the config file)

If I edit the xml config file like this:

```
<CodeGroup class="UnionCodeGroup" version="1" PermissionSetName="FullTrust">
    IMembershipCondition class="UrlMembershipCondition" version="1"
    Url="C:\PathToMyAssembly\MyAssembly.dll" />
</CodeGroup>
```

And then recycle the application pool, I can see that when my dll loads in a web application which uses the "WSS_Minimal" trust level, my assembly gets full trust.

How can I repeat this method using C# API only?

There are 3 main items -

1. Granting full trust to my assembly to a specific predefined trust level.
2. Checking whether "I already did that" - meaning, whether it is granted already.
3. Removing this (for example, when uninstalling my product)

It seems like using this API is the right place, however when I enumerated the policies, I never got to the xml I was looking for -

```
var levelEnumerator = SecurityManager.PolicyHierarchy();
while (levelEnumerator.MoveNext())
{
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try modify web.config through `SPWebConfigModification` class. And setup the `fullTrustAssemblies` section:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebConfigModification(v=office.15).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.web.configuration.fulltrustassembliessection(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Thanks! I didn't mention that this is required for SharePoint 2010 and up, so the _FullTrustAssembliesSection_ is irrelevant. However, _SPWebConfigModification_ is the answer for me. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest sticking with using caspol.exe. Not all of the functionality offered by the tool is exposed in the .NET framework so you best option would be to call caspol.exe either via C# code or PowerShell if you want to automate it.

If it's a custom DLL you are developing you can create a BAT file or a PowerShell file to copy the file to the desired location, run caspol.exe grant full trust to the assembly. You can also add checks in the by calling CasPol with the -resolveperm flag and parsing the output to check whether the assembly already has the correct security. This script can then be called as a Post Build command from Visual Studio to further automate the process.